# Query Firebase Database with limit

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just start to use firebase and it is quite useful.

I have node like this.

[image]

Currently, I wrote like this and it return all my messages. If I have 1k messages, it will return me 1k messages. I want to query only latest 100 message. Is it possible? Do I need to write cloud-function?

```
private void retrieveConversation(String conversationID) {

    Query queryRoom = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Conversation").child(conversationID);
    queryRoom.keepSynced(true);
    queryRoom.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Conversation conversation = dataSnapshot.getValue(Conversation.class);
            if (conversation != null) {
                conversation = updateConversation(conversation);
                mainMessage.conversations.put(conversation.getId(), conversation);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new ChatAdapter.AddMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Please try using limitToLast(int value) along with your query**

```
Query queryRoom = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Conversation").child(conversationID).limitToLast(100);
```

> **Or you can sort them by using timeStamp like**

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
.child("Conversation").child(conversationID)
.limitToLast(100)
.orderByChild("timestamp")
.startAt(dateToStart)    // pass timestamp from when you want to start filtering
.endAt(dateToEnd); // pass timestamp till when you want to apply filtering
```

Comment: ah great. I need to order by my own timestamp. Thanks thanks

Comment: Welcome Mate! Happy coding :)

Comment: where i could find more documentation about the query builder of fireabase?

Comment: @FernandoTorres: refer   https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Answer (score -1):

Or you can easily get them in firestore like this

```
firebase.firestore().collection('messages').limit(100).get()
```

Comment: The tag is for realtime-database not firestore